# Need some help on this computation problem

Tags: multithreading, performance

In this problem you are to compare reading a file using a single-threaded file server with a multi-threaded file server. It takes
    16 msec to get a request for work, dispatch it, and do the rest of the necessary processing, assuming the data are in the block
    cache. If a disk operation is needed (assume a spinning disk drive with 1 head), as is the case one-fourth of the time, an
    additional 32 msec is required. What is the throughput (requests/sec) if a multi-threaded server is required with 4-cores and
    4-threads, rounded to the nearest whole number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [CourseHero preview](https://www.coursehero.com/file/pmh97d/SOLUTIONS-TO-CHAPTER-3-PROBLEMS-1-Q-In-this-problem-you-are-to-compare-reading/) to see a similar problem that should sufficiently help you to complete this one.

Comment: How can i extend that to calculate throughput a 4-core and 4-threads?